# How to retrieve the URL of a Cloud Run service with Google Workflow?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-workflows

I am used to using CI / CD architecture for my deployments on Cloud Run. Each time a deployment has taken place, I have to manually retrieve the URL that I send to my employees by email. My goal is to automate this task with Google Workflow. How do I retrieve the URL of a new service or the tag of a Cloud Run service with Google Workflow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put together this returns the URL of a cloud run service

```
- initialize:
    assign:
      - project: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER")}
      - zone: us-central1
      - service: service
- getCloudRunDetails:
    call: http.get
    args:
        url: ${"https://"+zone+"-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/"+project+"/services/"+service+"?alt=json"}
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
    result: bitresult
- returnResult:
    return: ${bitresult.body.status.address.url}
```

the expected output is:

```
argument: 'null'
endTime: '2020-11-19T23:05:18.232772542Z'
name: projects/<edited>describeCloudRun/executions/<edited>   
result: '"https://<edited>uc.a.run.app"'
startTime: '2020-11-19T23:05:17.769640039Z'
state: SUCCEEDED
workflowRevisionId: 000020-b11
```

You have your value inside the `result` key.

Comment: You can also replace `return: ${bitresult.body.status.address.url}` by `return: ${bitresult.body.status.url}` to get the service link. With `return: ${bitresult.body.status.traffic[1].url}` we get the first review URL (tags). There can be multiple review URLs.

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done with `gcloud` CLI, however that's currently not an action supported in Cloud Workflows steps. Currently your only option is to use the [Get Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) REST API endpoint.

Here is an example:

```sh
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token -q)"
```

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/PROJECT_ID/services/SERVICE_NAME?alt=json
```

In the example above, note `us-central1` is the region and replace `PROJECT_ID` and `SERVICE_NAME` with yours.

The response will have a JSON document, and its `status.address.url` will contain the `https://[...].run.app` URL of your Cloud Run service.

Pro-tip: To find out what REST  API calls a `gcloud` command does (for example `gcloud run services describe`) add `--log-http` option.

Comment: Hi Ahmet, a small mistake: you have forgotten `Bearer` in the autorisation header ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Google now provides built-in workflows connectors, [including one for Cloud Run service](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/v1/Overview#Addressable,).

Getting the Cloud Run URL based on a service name can be done as below :

```
main:
    steps:
        - initialize:
              assign:
                  - project_number: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER")}
                  - cloud_run_location: europe-west2
                  - cloud_run_service_name: my-service-name
        - get_cloud_run_details:
            call: googleapis.run.v1.namespaces.services.get 
            args:
                name: ${"namespaces/" + project_number + "/services/" + cloud_run_service_name}
                location: ${cloud_run_location}
            result: service_obj
        - assign_vars:
              assign:
                  - service_url: ${service_obj.status.address.url}
```